# Get Selected Image File Location in Android

Tags: android, image, file-io, gallery

I am currently making an app which works with images.  I need to implement functionality where the user picks a file stored on the SD card.  Once they pick the picture (using the Android gallery), the the file-location of the image will be sent to another Activity, where other work will be done upon it.

I have seen similar posts here on SO, but none to answer my question specifically.  Basically this is the code I am doing when the user clicks the "Load a Picture" button:

```
// Create a new Intent to open the picture selector:
Intent loadPicture = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

// To start it, run the startActivityForResult() method:
startActivityForResult(loadPicture, SELECT_IMAGE);
```

From that code, I then have a `onActivityResult()` method to listen to the call-back:

```
// If the user tried to select an image:
if(requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE)
{
    // Check if the user actually selected an image:
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        // This gets the URI of the image the user selected:
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        // Create a new Intent to send to the next Activity:
        Intent i = new Intent(currentActivty.this, nextActivity.class);

        // ----------------- Problem Area -----------------
        // I would like to send the filename to the Intent object, and send it over.
        // However, the selectedImage.toString() method will return a
        // "content://" string instead of a file location.  How do I get a file
        // location from that URI object?
        i.putExtra("PICTURE_LOCATION", selectedImage.toString());

        // Start the activity outlined with the Intent above:
        startActivity(i);
```

As the code above states, the `uri.toString()` will return a `content://` string instead of the file location of the selected picture.  How do I obtain the file location?

Note: Another possible solution is to send over the `content://` string and convert that into a `Bitmap` (which is what happens in the next Activity).  However, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but I think I did something like
selectedImage.getPath();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question.  After doing some more searching, I finally stumbled upon a post here on SO which asks the same question here: [android get real path by Uri.getPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath).

Unfortunately, the answer has a broken link.  After some Google searching, I found the correct link to the site here: http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/130/ (I have verified that this code does indeed work.)

However, I decided to take a different route.  Since my next Activity is using an `ImageView` to display the picture, I am instead going to use the Uri content string for all methods that link to the next Activity.

In the next Activity, I am using the `ImageView.setImageUri()` method.

Here is the code I am doing in the next Activity to display the picture from the `content://` string:

```
// Get the content string from the previous Activity:
picLocation = getIntent().getStringExtra("PICTURE_LOCATION");

// Instantiate the ImageView object:
ImageView imageViewer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewer);

// Convert the Uri string into a usable Uri:
Uri temp = Uri.parse(picLocation);
imageViewer.setImageURI(temp);
```

I hope that this question and answer will be helpful to future Android developers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another answer that I hope someone finds useful:

You can do this for any content in the MediaStore.  In my app, I have to get the path from URIs and get the URI from paths.  The former:

```
/**
 * Gets the corresponding path to a file from the given content:// URI
 * @param selectedVideoUri The content:// URI to find the file path from
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the file path as a string
 */
private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedVideoUri,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    String filePath;
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaColumns.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedVideoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

The latter (which I do for videos, but can also be used for Audio or Files or other types of stored content by substituting MediaStore.Audio (etc) for MediaStore.Video:

```
/**
 * Gets the MediaStore video ID of a given file on external storage
 * @param filePath The path (on external storage) of the file to resolve the ID of
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the video ID as a long
 */
private long getVideoIdFromFilePath(String filePath,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {


    long videoId;
    Log.d(TAG,"Loading file " + filePath);

            // This returns us content://media/external/videos/media (or something like that)
            // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
            // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")
    Uri videosUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external");

    Log.d(TAG,"videosUri = " + videosUri.toString());

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID};

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    Log.d(TAG,"Video ID is " + videoId);
    cursor.close();
    return videoId;
}
```

Basically, the `DATA` column of `MediaStore` (or whichever sub-section of it you're querying) stores the file path, so you use what you know to look up the DATA, or you query on the `DATA` field to select the content you care about.