# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) when uploading an image to a website using POST

Tags: android

I saved the Uri String of an image to SQLite as string. I can view the image by creating a view intent for it.

but when I upload the image to the web server using FileBody(new File(theUriFromTheDatabase)) it always saying "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

The file's uri is: "/content:/media/external/images/media/667"

Facts:

1. I'm sure the file is there because I can view it
2. I enabled internal storage read/write, external storage read/write permissions
3. Using a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1
4. It doesn't have an SD card
5. Same code works on my Experia Neo V with SD card (is it because it has no SD card?)
6. Tried removing the wire before starting the app
7. Tethered USB is off

Here is the code:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InspectionsDbController db = new InspectionsDbController(getActivity());

        InspectionItemStruct[] ins = db.getInspectionList(((MyApplication)((Activity) mContext).getApplication()).getCurrentInspectionId());

        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        long userId = settings.getLong("userId", 0);
        String token = settings.getString("token", "");

        for (int i = 0; i < ins.length; i++) {


            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://webprojectupdates.com/mmp/api/mobile/upload_inspection");


                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                // add userId
                try {  
                    entity.addPart("userId", new StringBody(String.valueOf(userId)));
                    entity.addPart("token", new StringBody(String.valueOf(token)));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("MMP","Error in adding token: "+e.getMessage());
                }




                // add media attachments
                if(ins[i].image!=null){


                    //Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ins[i].image);

                    //ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    //image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                    //byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
                    //ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageData,"image/jpg", ins[i].itemId+".jpg");

                    //entity.addPart("image", bab);
                    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(new File (ins[i].image)));
                }
                if(ins[i].video!=null){
                    entity.addPart("video", new FileBody(new File (ins[i].video)));
                }

                // Normal string data
                try {  
                    entity.addPart("itemId", new StringBody(String.valueOf(ins[i].itemId)));
                    entity.addPart("isExist", new StringBody(String.valueOf(ins[i].itemExists)));
                    if(ins[i].comments!=null)  entity.addPart("comment", new StringBody(String.valueOf(ins[i].comments)));
                    entity.addPart("condition", new StringBody(String.valueOf(ins[i].condition)));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("MMP","Error in adding inspection data: "+e.getMessage());
                }

                try { 
                    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("MMP","Error in handling result: "+e.getMessage());
                }



            publishProgress(i+1,ins.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try passing in the uri as `URI` object to the `FileBody`'s file parameter, i.e.: `new File(new URI(theUriFromTheDatabase))`? Alternatively, use the uri to query `ContentResolver` and get the actual file location from the returned cursor, as [demonstrated here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9989900/1029225).

Comment: I did it like this File(Uri.parse(fromDb)) but it saying the constructor is not defined.

Comment: That's because `Uri` and `URI` are two different things (note the difference in capital chacaters). There's only a `File` constructor that takes the latter. In other words: parse the string from the database into an **[`URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)** and not an `Uri`.

Comment: doesn't work.. it causes the app to crash instead. btw, the string that is saved in the database looks like this: content://media/external/images/media/667

Comment: Pity. I think in that case your best bet is to either look up the actual file location using a `ContentResolver`. What also might work is to use `ContentResolver.openInputStream(theUriFromTheDatabase)` and replace the `FileBody` with an `InputStreamBody`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needed the filename instead if the uri string. thanks @mh

```
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
Cursor cur = cr.query(Uri.parse(ins[i].image), projection, null, null, null);
if(cur != null) {
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String filePath = cur.getString(0);
    File imageFile = new File(filePath);
    if(imageFile.exists()) {
        // do something if it exists
        entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(imageFile));
    }
    else {
        // File was not found
        Log.e("MMP","Image not Found");
    }
} 
else {
    // content Uri was invalid or some other error occurred
    Log.e("MMP","Invalid content or some error occured");
}
```

Comment: I have a uri from a just selected imagefile by the user.
How do I do what you have done here I don't understand the code properly.

Comment: I think there's another post for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore