# Copying data on assets folder to data folder of application throws no such file or directory error

Tags: java, android

I'm using the code below to copy the data containing files and folders with subfolders in them to data directory of my application but I get exception telling the destination location does not exist however `FileOutputStream` method should make the destination folders according to javadoc for this method:

`Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to path. The file will be truncated if it exists, and created if it doesn't exist.`

the code is :

```
    private void copyFileOrDir(String path) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    String assets[] = null;
    try {
        assets = assetManager.list(path);
        if (assets.length == 0) {
            copyFile(path);
        } else {
            String fullPath = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + path;
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();
            File innerDir;
            for (int i = 0; i < assets.length; ++i) {
                copyFileOrDir(path + "/" + assets[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("tag", "I/O Exception", ex);
    }
}

private void copyFile(String filename) {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(filename);
        String newFileName = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + filename;
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
                    //getting exception here...
        Log.e("mgh", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

logcat errors are like below for any folder :

```
09-06 15:14:20.981: E/mgh(19262): /data/data/ir.example.sampleapplication/pzl/ui/css/main.css: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: use mkdirs rather than mkdir. you apparently have several folders to create in your data dir (pzl/ui/css/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598389/open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-when-uploading-an-image-to-a-web  This seems to be similar...

Comment: what is the initial value of the `path` param ?

Comment: `path` param is the folder in assets that I want copy the files and folders in it

Answer (score 0):

/*I m using this code for copy data from assets folder just try it */
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.astrobix.numerodaily/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "Astrobix";
private static final String tag = "DatabaseHelperClass";
public static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
public final Context myContext;
public static String Table_Name="Prediction";
public static final String COL_ID="ID";
public static final String COL_HEAD="HEAD";
public static final String COL_VALUE="VALUE";
private static final String TABLE_QUESTIONS ="Prediction";

private static final String Create_Table="create table if not exists "
                                         +Table_Name
                                         +"("
                                         +COL_ID
                                         +" INTEGER primary key autoincrement , "
                                         +COL_HEAD
                                         +" TEXT, "
                                         +COL_VALUE
                                         + " VARCHAR); ";
```

//  public static String lastrecord;
//  public static String ratio="7:7";

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){        
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();     
        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;

    /* File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();*/
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("Astrobix.sqlite");

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE );     
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(Create_Table);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (db != null)
        onCreate(db);

}
```

Comment: @mgh-just add in permission in manifest.xml for external storage

Comment: but in this code openDatabase and getReadableDatabase methods create the database file before reaching to FileOutputStream

Comment: mgh-i m not understanding what u r saying.without creating blank database how to fill your database....

Comment: @mgh-because it is using for checking database empty or not