# Create File from Uri type android

Tags: java, android, file, uri, loopj

I'm trying to select image from gallery then convert this image to File and send it via HttpPost but I'm getting always `FileNotFoundException`. This my Code :

**Selecting the photo**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                //Save the currImageUri (URI type) to global variable.
                photosHolder.getInstance().setOneIm(currImageURI);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Converting the photo**

```
                // First Try
                File myFile = new File((photosHolder.getInstance().getOneIm()).toString());
                params.put("visit_report[photos_attributes][0][file]",myFile); **The exception Raised here
// second try 
                File myFile2 = new File((photosHolder.getInstance().getOneIm()).getPath());
                params.put("visit_report[photos_attributes][1][file]",myFile2); ** Also here
```

And those are myFiles Value while debuging :

```
mFile : content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A19143
myFile2 : /document/image:19143
```

So any help ?

---

**Update** 
I have tried this solution also :

```
//get The real path from uri then save it (and then use it to create the file)
photosHolder.getInstance().setUriString(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

//Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result = "";
        try {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
            result = cursor.getString(idx); // Exception raised HERE
            cursor.close(); }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it` and the `idx` var == to `-1`

Also I have tried @Praneeth Kalluri Solution but it returns always null as result.

Answer (score 6):

```
 Uri currImageURI = data.getData();
```

printing currImageURI will give you some thing like this:

```
content://media/external/images/media/47
```

But what we need is the absolute path of that particular image . So we need to get real path from uri

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Now modifiy your code like

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                // currImageURI is the global variable I’m using to hold the content:
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                //Save the currImageUri (URI type) to global variable.
                photosHolder.getInstance().setOneIm(getRealPathFromURI(getActivity(),currImageURI));
            }
        }
    }

public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The function you gave is always returning null .