# get name and full path of a file

Tags: android, file, android-internal-storage

I used Intent `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to show recent files from phone memory. That includes images, pdf, google drive documents(pdf, xlsx) as shown in screenshot below. I want to get the name and full path so that I can upload the file to server. I/m getting the mime type correctly as of now.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    TextView txt;
    private final static int EXTERNAL = 111;
    private final static int ATTACH = 11;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        photoIntent();
                    } else {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                            // showToast("Permission Required...");
                        }
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL);
                    }


                } else {

                    photoIntent();
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private void photoIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), ATTACH);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, String[] permission, int[] grantRes){

        if (requestcode == EXTERNAL) {
            if (grantRes[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                photoIntent();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to Access Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == ATTACH && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            System.out.println("sammy_sourceUri "+uri);
            String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
            System.out.println("sammy_mimeType "+ mimeType);
            


        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath

Comment: There is no real path. Just use [ContentResolver.openInputStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri))

Comment: Can we upload the file (either zip file or google drive file) to server using ` ContentResolver.openInputStream()` ? @ianhanniballake

Comment: Well yeah, you have full access to the contents of the selected file

Comment: Let's suppose I get the InputStream of the google drive pdf or xlsx, but how to use this InputStream to upload to server API as file? Do I need to convert InputStream to file or ByteArrayBody to upload? @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the name and full path so that I can upload the file to server

There is no "full path", because there may not be a "file".

You are invoking `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. This returns a `Uri` to some content. Where that content comes from is up to the developers of the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity that the user chose. That could be:

- An ordinary file on the filesystem that happens to be one that you could access
- An ordinary file on the filesystem that resides somewhere that you cannot access, such as internal storage for the other app
- A file that requires some sort of conversion for it to be useful, such as decryption
- A `BLOB` column in a database
- Content that is generated on the fly, the way this Web page is generated on the fly by the Stack Overflow servers
- And so on

To use the content from the `Uri`, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`.

> how to use this InputStream to upload to server API as file?

Either your chosen HTTP API supports an `InputStream` as the source of this content, or it does not. If it does, just use the `InputStream` directly. If not, use the `InputStream` to make a temporary copy of the content as a file that you *can* directly access (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), upload that file, then delete the file when the upload is complete.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  public static ArrayList<String> getImagesFromCameraDir(Context context) {
        Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED};
        Cursor mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, columns, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[]{"%/DCIM/%"}, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();

            try {
                int uploadImage = 0;
                uploadImage = mCursor.getCount();
                for (int index = 0; index < uploadImage; index++) {
                    mCursor.moveToPosition(index);
                    int idx = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                    filePaths.add(mCursor.getString(idx));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mCursor.close();
            }
        }
        return filePaths;
    }
```

Comment: What about if the file is not image? That where problem is. May be its a google drive file or a zip file or a simple pdf. @UmaAchanta

Answer (score 0):

get real path from URI

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
{
     String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
     int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

FILENAME :

```
String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```