# Real name of the image when I select from the gallery

Tags: android

When select image from gallery, the uri is: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/**image:49769**

and i need: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/**image.jpg**

How do I get the actual name of the image?

I have this now:

```
if(requestCode==REQ_CODE_PICTURE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data != null &&    data.getData() != null) {

fileUri = data.getData();
imageView.setImageURI(fileUri);

Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

File f = new   File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileUri.getPathSegments().get(fileUri.getPathSegments().size()-1));

Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath());
//uriToUpload = contentUri.toString();
uriToUpload = getRealPathFromURI(contentUri);
Log.i("AAAAAAA", uriToUpload);



public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index =   cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

And this is the error in cursor.moveToFirst():

12-19 11:39:16.469 5096-5096/com.example.formador.a42_camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.formador.a42_camera, PID: 5096
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:49769 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.formador.a42_camera/com.example.formador.a42_camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3798)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3841)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.formador.a42_camera.MainActivity.getRealPathFromURI(MainActivity.java:163)
                                                                                   at com.example.formador.a42_camera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:147)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6490)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3794)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3841) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: any code you have in place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android get real path by Uri.getPath()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath)

Answer (score 0):

Get the real path from your uri

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it gives me the error that I put up

Answer (score 0):

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.pickiimagefromgallery_android_examples.com.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Select Image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static int IMG_RESULT = 1;
    String ImageDecode;
    ImageView imageViewLoad;
    Button LoadImage;
    Intent intent;
    String[] FILE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewLoad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        LoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        LoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_RESULT);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == IMG_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri URI = data.getData();
                String[] FILE = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(URI,
                        FILE, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(FILE[0]);
                ImageDecode = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Log.i("ImageDecode", "+++" + ImageDecode);
                imageViewLoad.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(ImageDecode));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```