# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have following method to pass selected image path to another activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Log.d("fsd", "onActivityResult: ");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddContentImage.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("path", selectedImagePath);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is actually working fine, but I gets following error, when back button is pressed.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3169)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3247)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
      at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:63)
      at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:132)
      at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:228)
      at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6363)
      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6389)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3247) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
```

This error only occurs if second activity is opened from `onActivityResult`.

**Edited:**

getpath method

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    // just some safety built in
    if( uri == null ) {
        // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
        return null;
    }
    // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
    // this will only work for images selected from gallery
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
    // this is our fallback here
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: "which is actually working fine" -- probably not. Delete `getPath()`, as there is no valid implementation of such a method. "I gets following error, when back button is pressed" -- if I had to guess, you are using the `managedQuery()` method, which has been deprecated for six years. You might want to edit your question and show the code where you are obtaining your `Cursor`.

Comment: I have added the getpath method.

Comment: Got it resolved by using solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

First, `managedQuery()` has been deprecated **for over six years**. Do not use it. Use a `CursorLoader`, or use `ContentResolver` and `query()` on some form of background thread.

Second, be sure to follow the instructions of the things that you use. In this case, you missed [the instructions for using `managedQuery()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)):

> Warning: Do not call close() on a cursor obtained using this method, because the activity will do that for you at the appropriate time.

Beyond that, a `Uri` does not point to a file in most cases, and so you cannot get a "real path" to that file.