# How to get real path of capture image and gallery image in android in android 10 and above

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, gallery

for getting the real path of capture image and gallery image the following code work perfectly fine for me.

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String result = null;
        try{
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(requireActivity(), contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("error_getting_path",e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

but in android 10 and above device i am not able to get the path of capture and gallery image .
so my app is not working in android 10 and above for this feature.
please suggest the best way to get path in all android devices.

Comment: The .DATA column is not used on Android 10 and 11. The best way is not try to get a path from a nice uri (a nasty habbit anyhow) but to use the uri directly. You dont need a path... well.. mostly not.

Comment: File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(contentUri));

        RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("image",file.getName(),requestFile)
                .build();

Comment: this is my approact to upload the file using path of selected or capture image how can i do this without having the path of file. file creating from uri is not working for .. @blackapps

Comment: There is something like .addStreamUri..... Sorry forgot the name. Have a look. The ide gives you a choose.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private static String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Uri returnUri = uri;
    Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex( OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);

    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

      
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

        final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
        }
      
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: This has no effect as the .DATA column will stay null.

Comment: this is working in my demo you have to use   android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in mainfest inside application tag and did you add File Provider

Comment: `This has no effect as the .DATA column will stay null. `

Comment: where i use DATA  i didnt use , can you check and replace my method with YOur

Comment: Can be. But this is ridiculous code as you make a copy of the file first and then return the path of the copy instead of that from the original file. And then pretending that you get 'the real path'. Name it getPathOfACopy instead.

Comment: yes this is ridiculous but wht to do . android 10 above policies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2790688/4331682 you can check here about this TOPIc