# How to get file path from content uri using chooser intent?

Tags: android, file, kotlin

When I select any pdf file from storage and open it through chooser intent(Intent_View), I want to get the path of that file in this intent.

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    receivedIntent = intent
    receivedType = receivedIntent?.type
    if (receivedIntent?.data != null) {
        receivedUri = receivedIntent?.data!!
        Log.i("path", "onNewIntent: ${receivedIntent?.data!!}")
        if (receivedType == "application/pdf"){
            findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView).navigate(R.id.pdfReader)
        } else if(receivedType == "application/epub+zip"){
            findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView).navigate(R.id.epubFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a dublicated question I think, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath.

Comment: @hcc My question is excatly like this...But i want to fetch uri of PDF file...What should I do in this situation?